# How to silence or mute part of a clip in Adobe Premiere?

Tags: premiere

One of my favorite parts of Final Cut Pro is the ability to select part of a clip and silence it with a single shortcut (which adds 4 keyframes automatically):

[image]

Is it possible to do this in Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2020?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the closest thing that I've found so far is to:

1. Make a cut with the razor tool
2. Select the audio part with `alt + click`
3. Toggle Enable clip with `shift + command + e` (to disable the audio)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use razor tool (C) to make cuts at the beginning and end of the section of audio that you want removed.
2. Switch to the pointer tool (V), then click the section of audio
3. Press the Delete key to remove that section.

Answer (score 1):

To minimise mousing around:

1. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> +<kbd>K</kbd> with the razor
2. <kbd>Space</kbd> Play to the next point (and stop)
3. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to make the next cut
4. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>up arrow</kbd> to select previous clip
5. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to mute that region

"Select previous clip" always selects based on the clip that is currently selected (highlighted in white). Sometimes that won't be the clip nearest your playhead. You may have to tap <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>up arrow</kbd> or down arrow a few times to get to your clip.